# UMP test with level $\alpha$ has size $\alpha$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference

I have been reading theorems about uniformly most powerful (UMP) tests of level $\alpha$, and in all of them the UMP test has size $\alpha$, but I don't know if it always happens... This is, if there is UMP test in a class of tests with level $\alpha$, the UMP has size ??

Comment: I doubt there is much difference in meaning between *size* and *level*.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)) says "A test is said to have significance level $\alpha$ if its size is less than or equal to $\alpha$. In many cases the size and level of a test are equal."

Comment: A test of size $\alpha$ is a test of level $\alpha$. A test of level  $\alpha$ is a test in which $\sup_{\theta \in H_{0}}<=\alpha$ and has size $\alpha$ if they are equal. My question is if the UMP of level $\alpha$ is always the one which size $\alpha$

Comment: sup is of the power function of the test

Comment: It can be argued that the 'best' test among all level $\alpha$ tests is the 'best' test of size $\alpha$, where 'best' means the test which minimizes both probability of type I error and probability of type II error (although no such test exists for fixed sample size). So you often see *size $\alpha$ test* and *level $\alpha$ test* used interchangeably.